# For Loop HTML/JS , weekly descending numbers

Tags: html, loops, for-loop

I'm trying out For Loop and I ran into a problem. So the goal here is that the body weight should drop 10% in 7 weeks. I'm having a problem with the weekly weight loss, as you can see it only shows the end weight every week. Where do I go wrong? What is missing? TIA!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Weight loss</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <p>
      <label> Weight: </label>
      <input type="text" id="stWeight" size="5">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="button" value="Goal weight" onclick="showGoal()">
    </p>
  </form>

  <div id="answer"></div>
  <script>
    function showGoal() {

      var stWeight = Number(document.getElementById("stWeight").value);
      var wklyLoss = stWeight * 0.1 / 7;
      var text = "";
      for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {

        weight = stWeight - wklyLoss;


        text += i + ". week " + weight.toFixed(2) + "<br>";


      }

      document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "<p>" + text + "</p>";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are doing the same calcul each time. ( the starting weight minus one weeklyLoss )

Before the loop initialize the "weight" variable with the stWeight value , then do  the following inside your loop instead of your actual calcul;

```
weight -= wklyLoss;
```

so the weight will decrease each iteration

Comment: I´m not sure if I understand what you mean. Could you please guide me through step by step how/where I can use the solution you mentioned above... since I am a dumb beginner.

Answer (score 0):

It‘s only a math problem which you may want to solve inside the loop

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Weight loss</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <p>
      <label> Weight: </label>
      <input type="text" id="stWeight" size="5">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="button" value="Goal weight" onclick="showGoal()">
    </p>
  </form>

  <div id="answer"></div>
  <script>
    function showGoal() {

      var stWeight = Number(document.getElementById("stWeight").value);
     
      var text = "";
      for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        var wklyLoss = stWeight * 0.1 / (8-i);
        weight = stWeight - wklyLoss;


        text += i + ". week " + weight.toFixed(2) + "<br>";


      }

      document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "<p>" + text + "</p>";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```